# How to calculate finish date time in any timezone given the work hours needed and the Working Hours in PT timezone

Tags: momentjs, moment-timezone, luxon

Using JavaScript and moment library, given the user's now, number of hours and minutes needed to complete the job, and the following table of open and close hours at the shop in Seattle.

*Working hours in Pacific time zone*

[image: Working hours in Pacific time zone]

I need to predict the date & time a job will be finished in the user's time zone by the shop in Seattle.

Can anyone show an example or suggest an algorithm to follow?

The programming langue does not matter, I can translate to JavaScript.

If there is an example using the 'moment' library it is even better.

Thank you much.

Examples:

1. If it is now Monday 8AM in PT and the job takes 3 hours, it will finish at Monday 11AM in PT because it does not hit a time that the shop is closed.
2. if the job takes 30 hours, then (22-8= 14 ) on Monday , 2+4 = 6 close time , (30-14) = 16 on Tuesday make the completion = Tuesday 4PM in PT (this to demonstrate just one closing time).
3. If the user is in NYC then his Monday 8AM , is 4AM in PT and there will be 22 hours to do the 30 hours job On Monday, 2+4 = 6 close time , (30-22) = 8 on Tuesday 8AM PT is Tuesday 4AM ET so for the NYC user, the completion is Tuesday 4AM.
4. Long jobs can traverse more than one closing time range and the weekend can add more.

We have users in all USA time zones and maybe soon in UK and DE but only one shop in Seattle

Comment: The difference between CloseTime and OpenHour will give you the number of hours they can work on a day right? So 22 - 13 on sunday = 9 hours right?

Comment: Yes. I should have call it Close Hour. So every day, number of hours they work is closeTime -OpenHour

Comment: How does the open/close time relate to the time the a job will be finished? Maybe you can give some examples of input and expected output?

Comment: Hilton See above. as with the reviews, I am surprise something like this does not Show right away when you google it. :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you want to use is subtraction. Start with a list of duration available for each day. Keep a variable with the duration remaining. Find the number of hours remaining on the starting date and subtract that, or the duration remaining itself from the duration remaining - whichever is less. Repeat for subsequent days until the duration remaining is zero. If say on the last day there are still 4 hours remaining in their working day then subtract those 4 hours from their end of day to get the time they will finish the job.

It'll probably help to break everything down to integer milliseconds. Leave the conversion to the timestamp until the end.

Comment: But how to you factor possible time zone difference? the shop is always in PT but users can be in ET, CT or MT.

Comment: Check the momentjs api docs for how to pass the date, hours, minutes and time zone (PT) to 'parse' the date into a moment object. Then you can 'format' the moment object in whatever time zone you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it.
Who cares to check my logic Using Luxon.JS?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Job Done with LuxonJS</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <style>
    #output {
      font-size: 2rem;
    }
    
    #output2 {
      font-size: 2rem;
      /* color: red; */
    }
    
    #output3 {
      font-size: 2rem;
      color: green;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Calculating Completion Date Time</h1>
  </header>
  <main>
    <div id="output"></div>
    <div id="output2"></div>
    <div id="output3"></div>
  </main>
  <!-- <script src="luxon.min.js"></script>-->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/luxon@1.24.1/build/global/luxon.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    Number.prototype.between = function(a, b, inclusive) { //For elegant If statment
      var min = Math.min.apply(Math, [a, b]),
        max = Math.max.apply(Math, [a, b]);
      return inclusive ? this >= min && this <= max : this > min && this < max;
    };
    console.clear();
    //weekday: number  Get the day of the week. 1 is Monday and 7 is Sunday
    var OpenClose = [{}, // elemnt 0 not used to make Luxon Day Of the Week the index into the array 
      {
        dw: 'Monday',
        open: 4,
        close: 22,
        LuxonDayOfWeek: 1
      },
      {
        dw: 'Tuesday',
        open: 4,
        close: 22,
        LuxonDayOfWeek: 2
      },
      {
        dw: 'Wedneday',
        open: 4,
        close: 22,
        LuxonDayOfWeek: 3
      },
      {
        dw: 'Thursday',
        open: 4,
        close: 22,
        LuxonDayOfWeek: 4
      },
      {
        dw: 'Friday',
        open: 4,
        close: 19,
        LuxonDayOfWeek: 5
      },
      {
        dw: 'Saturday',
        open: 6,
        close: 18,
        LuxonDayOfWeek: 6
      },
      {
        dw: 'Sunday',
        open: 13,
        close: 22,
        LuxonDayOfWeek: 7
      }
    ]; //orderby 
    console.log(OpenClose); //Show the Shop Schedule
    let DateTime = luxon.DateTime;
    var local = DateTime.local(); //Now here
    //Make changes here !!
    let Remainghours = 12.15; //Time alotted for the job. Change to test other values. 

    var NowInPT = local.setZone("America/Los_Angeles"); //Seattle is in this TimeZone
    let JobDonePT = NowInPT; //Start at same time
    output.textContent = "Starting in PT on " + NowInPT.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT) + " Job takes " + Remainghours + " hours";
    while (Remainghours > 0) {
      if (JobDonePT.hour.between(OpenClose[JobDonePT.weekday].open, OpenClose[JobDonePT.weekday].close, true)) {
        console.log("Shop Open: " + JobDonePT.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT) + " DW=" + JobDonePT.weekday + " " + Remainghours + " Hours outstanding");
        Remainghours--; //Shop is open Use up an hour
      } else {
        console.log("Shop Closed: " + JobDonePT.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT) + " DW=" + JobDonePT.weekday + " " + Remainghours + " Hours outstanding");
        //keep going without Using Remainghours 
      }
      JobDonePT = JobDonePT.plus({
        hours: 1
      }); //advance 1 hour on the calendar in any case
    }
    // Now we are left with a Negative fraction of an hour so we set set the actual Completion
    JobDonePT = JobDonePT.plus({
      hours: Remainghours
    }); //Remainghours is negative
    //The end DateTime may still be in Off hours Must end In work hours so
    while (!JobDonePT.hour.between(OpenClose[JobDonePT.weekday].open, OpenClose[JobDonePT.weekday].close, true)) { //Not working hours
      debugger;
      JobDonePT = JobDonePT.plus({
        hours: 1
      });
    };
    output2.textContent = "Job End in PT on " + JobDonePT.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT);
    var JobDoneMylocal = JobDonePT.toLocal();
    output3.textContent = "Job End in My Time Zone on " + JobDoneMylocal.toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_SHORT);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```